# Prettier causing "typos"

Tags: reactjs, webstorm, prettier

The short story is, when I commit with WebStorm and the code is formatted –– by Prettier, I think –– sometimes this:

```
<div
  style={{
    color: Globals.COLOR.gold,
    fontSize: 16,
    marginBottom: 2,
  }}>
```

Will become this:

```
<div
  style={{
    color: Globals.COLOR.gold,
    fontSize: 16,
    marginBottom: ,
  }}>
```

See how it cuts of the actual value from `marginBottom`? Obviously this breaks the app completely.

It also does things like this:

```
<div
  style={{
    color: Globals.COLOR.lightgray,
    fontSize: 11,
  }}>
  FPP
</div>
```

becomes

```
<div
  style={{
    color: Globals.COLOR.lightgray,
    fontSize: 11
  }}>
  FPP
</div>
```

Removing the comma after `11`, which doesn't break things. But is maybe a clue.

I’ve had some responses that I’m writing the styles wrong. I don’t think that’s the issue, but I’ll also point out that other instances of the problem include something like

```
let obj = { 
  key: value 
}
```

becoming

```
let obj = { 
  key: valu
}
```

Please let me know what more information you need. I imagine there's a lot of config questions before help can be given.

Here's some though:

`.prettierrc`

```json
{
    "bracketSpacing": true,
    "jsxBracketSameLine": true,
    "singleQuote": false,
    "arrowParens": "avoid",
    "trailingComma": "all",
    "printWidth": 120
}
```

I also have a pretty immense `eslintrc.js`. I'll post it if you want but it's reeeeeal big.

Comment: marginBottom is a length or a percentage, so it was broken beforehand

Comment: Well that doesn’t actually help with the actual question.

Comment: What I may suggest: 1) Disable any Prettier integration in WebStorm (it has "run on save" option AFAIK). 2) Once you make your changes and save the file, go to OS terminal (not IDE built-in one) and run Prettier for that file -- do you have the same behaviour? 3) If still the same: A) Try making a brand new project (even empty one); add minimal code/tools and repeat the same -- any difference. B) Try downgrading Prettier to 1-2 versions back (or upgrade to the latest if it's not the one) -- maybe it's an issue with current one.

Comment: Thanks for the great suggestions! I’ll try once the week starts again. How now I’ve turned off Format on Commit which is basically good enough

Comment: can be related to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-49300, please feel free to add your comments there